# Rendering into DOM for each element in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JS Object filled with objects nested within those. If you'd rather have specifics, it's a "projects" object for my portfolio, with 7 projects in it that each have a title, description, details and an image url. This is how it's set up:

```
const projects = {
  0: {
    title: "Project name",
    description:
      "A cool description",
    details: [
      "First detail",
      "Second point",
      "Third item"
    ].map(detail => <li>{detail}</li>),
    image: "image_url"
  },
  1: { ... },
  2: { ... },
  ...
```

Now, based on this data I want to render one div element per item into the DOM, which doesn't seem to be working well. I've tried multiple ways, and I ended up being able to pass the 'projects' constant as a prop to where I need it, but since it's an Object instead of an array, I can't seem to use the map method on it (you can see that I used that method to render list items).

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
function ProjectList(props) {
  const projects = props.projects;
  const projectItems = projects.map(project => <h1>Test</h1>);

  return <ul>{projectItems}</ul>;
}
```

And then down in render function...

```
<ProjectList projects={projects} />
```

Expectations: 7 h1 tags saying Test (I think I could take it from there if this would render)

Good news: the projects constant within ProjectList does return the appropriate object.

Bad news: *"projects.map is not a function"*

So, basically what I guess I am asking is a way to effectively iterate through a nested Object and render an element into the DOM each time. I'm sorry if it's a very basic thing but this is my first react project and I've tried all I could think of.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: `projects` is an object. Use `Object.values(projects).map`

Comment: `projects` should be an array, if you want to guarantee that the elements are in the correct order.  then you can easily do stuff like `projects.map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by someone else, you can't map an object, but you can map over the keys of the object using

```
Object.keys(projects).map( key => <h1>{projects[key].title}</h1>)
```

Since you are using integer based keys for your projects object, you'd be better off declaring it as an array like this:

```
const projects = [
    {
        title: "Project name",
        description: "A cool description",
        details: [
            "First detail",
            "Second point",
            "Third item"
        ].map(detail => <li>{detail}</li>),
        image: "image_url"
    },
    { ... },
    { ... }
]
```

Then you can just use

```
projects.map(project => <h1>Test</h1>);
```

if you need the index of the element for some reason, you can use

```
projects.map((project, index) => <h1>Project {project.title} is index {index}</h1>);
```

Answer (score 1):

the big problem is that the projects is an Object, so does not have the map array function. Maybe this example it will be useful.

[Example Map using React using Objecj as Array](https://codepen.io/joeltonmats/pen/rgdowP?editors=1010)

```
const projects = {
  0: {
    title: "Project name",
    description:
      "A cool description",
    details: [
      "First detail",
      "Second point",
      "Third item"
    ],
    image: "image_url"
  },
  1: {
    title: "Project name 2",
    description:
      "A cool description",
    details: [
      "First detail",
      "Second point",
      "Third item"
    ],
    image: "image_url"
  }
};

function ProjectItem(props) {
  return (
    <li>{props.item.title}</li>
  );
}


function ProjectList () {

  const newProjects = Object.values(projects);
  console.log('teste',newProjects);

  return (
    <ul>
      {newProjects.map(item =>
        <ProjectItem key={item.title} item={item} />
       )}
    </ul>
  );
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <ProjectList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```